# proof that set is semi-linear

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Set linear: $\{a+bn | n\in \mathbb{N} \}; a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ 
Set semi-linear: $finite$ sum of linear sets: $\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}L_i$; $L_i$ is linear.

Prove that set $$A=\{a+b_1n_1+...+b_kn_k | n_1,...n_k\in \mathbb{N}\}$$ is semi-linear.

### 1ST SOLUTION

So let's try,
Let $b=b_1...b_k$
Let $m_i\equiv i (\mod b)$, where $m_i\in A$ and is smallest number.
$i=0,1,...b-1$
And now, $$\bigcup_{i=0}^{b-1}\{m_i+bn | n\in\mathbb{N}\} = A$$

### EDIT TO 1ST SOLUTION

What about situation that there is no $m_i\in A$ such that $m_i\equiv i (\mod b) $ It isn't problem, because I must show that $m_i\in A \rightarrow m_i+bn
\in A (where\ n=1,..n)$
There are exists $n_1,...,n_k$ such that $$bn = b_1n_1+...+b_kn_k $$ It is because of the fact that $$gcd(b_1,b_2,...,b_k)\ |\ [bn=(b_1...b_k)n]$$

So, $$\{m_i+bn | n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq A$$Because of $i=0...b-1$
$$\bigcup_{i=0}^{b-1}\{m_i+bn | n\in\mathbb{N}\} = A$$
Ok now ?

### Second solution:

I use following fact:
$$\exists_{n_0\in\mathbb{N}}\forall_{n\ge n_0, d|n+a}\exists_{n_1,..,n_k\in \mathbb{N}}\ \ \ \  a+b_1n_1+...+b_kn = n$$
$gcd (b_1,...,b_k)=d$
Then, $$A=\{n_0+dn\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup \{ A\cap\{0,1,..,n_0\}\}$$

Comment: You should justify the last statement better. It's true, but simply writing true statements without justification doesn't make a correct answer. (And, for completeness, you should say what happens when $m_i$ isn't defined).

Comment: I edited my post, look again please